# Raw output for debugging API in Laravel 5?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am having troubles with larval because the `dd()` functions returns with a lots of HTML on it. Since I am debugging an API with cURL on my terminal I want to see the raw output with no additional HTML.

Any solution for disabling the new `dd()` feature and rather use it like in Laravel 4?

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/the-new-dd-in-laravel-5-is-kind-of-shitty

Comment: try `echo '<pre>'; print_r($response); die;`  if you response is a model or a collection convert to array by adding  `->toArray();` to your query.

Comment: That seems to work! Didn't think about that. Thanks!